# Can't run Chargebee API with node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new to this API so I'm trying to run it with node.js but It seems not to be working, so I'm stuck. Can anyone who had already used ChargeBee API with Node please help me. Thank you

Comment: what is the error and what have you tried so far?

Comment: It's my first time using it so, I only installed it using npm then the authentication, after I tried using one of its function like retrieve a subscription in Node server side. but it gives me not able to load require  error

Answer (score 1):

Could you add more information regarding your issue with some code snippet.

Here is an example on how to use chargebee API in node:

```
var chargebee = require("chargebee");

chargebee.configure({site : "<<site_name>>",
  api_key : "<<api_key>>"});

  var getSubDetails = function(subId, callback){
    chargebee.subscription.retrieve(subId).request(
    function(error,result){
      if(error){
        //handle error
        console.log(error);
      }else{
        var subscription = result.subscription;
        var customer = result.customer;
        var card = result.card;
        callback(subscription, customer);
      }
    });
  }

  getSubDetails("<<subID>>", function(subscription, customer){// calling function by passing chargebee subscription ID.
     console.log(subscription);
     console.log(customer);
  });
```